# Creating sub-categories in Django Admin without creating a new app

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I was wandering wether it is possible to create sub-categories for models in the Django administration panel.

Let's assume I have an app called "MyApp" which contains 2 model classes called "foo" and "bar". In my admin panel I will see the name of the the app and my two models listed under it (once registered in admin.py).

What I want is to create a sub-category in the admin panel which would look like this:

1. MyApp
2. first model name --> new sub category
3. foo
4. second model name --> new sub cateogry
5. bar

Thank you for your time,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use **django admin plus** to create a new admin view easly and put whatever you want into it .

Link >>> [github repo](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus)